# OBJ Export (Pivot Points Wrong)

Tags: objects, export, unity, obj

I believe I've tried every export setting I can think of. I'd like objects I export from Blender to keep their pivot point, but they never seem to do that. Is there a secret way to do this, or does Blender not have that ability??

Thank you for your time!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to correct the origins in blender. While the four cubes are selected, right click to bring up this panel.

[image]

Then navigate to 'set origin' and select the 'origin to 3d cursor'. This will set the four cubes origins to the cursor position and you should be good to go! Then inside unity, make sure to set tool handle position to 'pivot'.

Hopefully this works!

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't really matter where you set the origin, the origin will always be at the center of the world $(0,0,0)$ when exporting OBJ. so in case you want to have a custom pivot point you should:

1. Select the objects you want to share a single pivot for them
2. Place the 3D Cursor wherever you want the pivot point to be.
3. Set the origins to cursor via *Object > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*
4. while still selecting the objects press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to reset the positions to center (with the new origin)
5. Export OBJ

Now all the objects will have the same custom pivot but when importing to unity (or other programs) the positions would be still at the center of the world and in unity you have to place the objects manually.